# Unknow column in having clause - mysql

Tags: sql, mysql, having

I know this has been answered, but I can't decipher the solution from the responses given my lack of experience with mysql, so forgive me for asking the same question again. I am converting ms-access queries to mysql and that is a world of hurt for me...the problem I am having is I get the 'Uknown column `Big Ditch`.`Begindate` in 'having clause'.

I tried this:

```
SELECT Sum(datediff(`Big Ditch`.`EndDate`,`Big Ditch`.`BeginDate`)*`Big Ditch`.`Amount`) AS `BigDitchTotal`, extract(year from `Big Ditch`.`BeginDate`) AS Expr1
FROM `Big Ditch`
GROUP BY (extract(year from `Big Ditch`.`BeginDate`))
HAVING (extract(year from `Big Ditch`.`BeginDate`) = current_date());
```

Comment: `HAVING` conditions are checked after aggregating, so it doesn't make sense to test columns in the original table. You should use `WHERE` for this.

Comment: Thanks for the quick rely. When I replace HAVING with WHERE I get red squiggly underline under WHERE saying it is not valid at this position...

Comment: Of course. `WHERE` goes before `GROUP BY`. This is basic SQL.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I could use some sql training for sure. As I said, I am trying to convert access database to mysql with no sql experience. Wish me luck.

Comment: How can you compare a year to a specific date?

Comment: Since you already assign the `Expr1` alias to the year, you can use `GROUP BY Expr1 HAVING Expr1 = YEAR(current_date())`

Comment: Yes, the query returned nothing, so my check is invalid...I was just searching how to get year from current date...

Comment: But it's generally best to do `WHERE` filtering before aggregation, since it doesn't have to process as much data.

Comment: @Barmar: YOU ARE THE MAN! I wish you were on my team! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter the rows by year before doing the aggregation to reduce the amount of data that has to be processed.

MySQL has a built-in `YEAR()` function that you can use instead of `EXTRACT()`.

You don't need `GROUP BY` because you're only displaying the result for one year, which is the one you select in the `WHERE` condition.

```
SELECT Sum(datediff(`Big Ditch`.`EndDate`,`Big Ditch`.`BeginDate`)*`Big Ditch`.`Amount`) AS `BigDitchTotal`, MAX(YEAR(`Big Ditch`.`BeginDate`)) AS Expr1
FROM `Big Ditch`
WHERE YEAR(`Big Ditch`.`BeginDate`) = YEAR(current_date())
```

Comment: I would thumbs up your response, but I get an error: Error Code: 1140. In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #2 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'gmwua_alpha.Big Ditch.BeginDate'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: Your previous reply was successful.

Comment: Adding an aggregation function around it fixes it, I've updated the answer.

Comment: Nice! Thanks again Barmar!

Comment: The condition `YEAR(BeginDate) = YEAR(current_date())` can make this query really slow. Might be faster to write it out as `BeginDate >= '2023-01-01' AND BeginDate <= '2023-12-31'`

Comment: @JonasMetzler Assuming there's an index on `BeginDate`.